# wso2 esb configuration reset feature not working

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

WSO2 esb configuration page (under source view) says

> Make the required modifications to the configuration and click
>   'Update' to apply the changes to the server. Use 'Reset' button to
>   undo your changes.

When I do a change and click update the configuration gets updated, but when I do a reset, it does not undo the changes. what is the problem here?is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

It resets only the unsaved changes. When you click update and then immediately click reset nothing will happen since the changes are saved when you update.

But if the reset button doesn't work at all (popup confirmation doesn't appear), then this can be due to a browser compatibility issue, so try with a different browser and see.

Comment: is there a way to save the current configuration, and import it at a later time?

Comment: afaik that's not possible... but you can probably save them in registry. If you want a more feature-rich editor, use Developer studio: http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/

Answer (score 0):

> Make the required modifications to the configuration and click 'Update' to apply the changes to the server. Use 'Reset' button to undo your changes.

It means that while you are doing the changes in the source view, at the middle of changing, you can click 'Update' to save the current changes and you can click 'Reset' to clear/undo the changes currently you are doing. But if you click 'Update' and then 'Reset', it will not undo the changes which are already saved.

Comment: well. that explains it. Thanks